# Simple SQL Query to bring back null if no match found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join

### EDIT

I've edited this question to make it a little more concise, if you see my edit history you will see my effort and 'what I've tried' but it was adding a lot of unnecessary noise and causing confusion so here is a summary of input and output:

```
People:

ID | FullName
--------------------
1  | Jimmy
2  | John
3  | Becky

PeopleJobRequirements:

ID | PersonId | Title
--------------------
1  | 1        | Some Requirement
2  | 1        | Another Requirement     
3  | 2        | Some Requirement
4  | 3        | Another Requirement
```

Output:

```
FullName | RequirementTitle
---------------------------
Jimmy    | Some Requirement
Jimmy    | Another Requirement
John     | Some Requirement
John     | null
Becky    | null
Becky    | Another Requirement
```

Each person has 2 records, because that's how many distinct requirements there are in the table (distinct based on 'Title').

Assume there is no third table - the 'PeopleJobRequirements' is unique to each person (one person to many requirements), but there will be duplicate Titles in there (some people have the same job requirements).

Sincere apologies for any confusion caused by the recent updates.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: Questions like this are always more clear when you provide us with sample data and expected result

Comment: @GuidoG - good point, I'll add that now....

Comment: @PSK - apologies - I did suspect I was causing some confusion! I will check the answer now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CROSS JOIN` to get equal record for each person and `LEFT JOIN` for matching records.

Following query should work in your scenario

```
select p.Id, p.FullName,r.Title
FROM People p
cross join (select distinct title from PeopleJobRequirements )  pj
left join  PeopleJobRequirements r on  p.id=r.personid and pj.Title=r.Title
order by fullname
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/NJEC55671)

**Output**

```
+----+----------+---------------------+
| Id | FullName | Title               |
+----+----------+---------------------+
| 3  | Becky    | Another Requirement |
+----+----------+---------------------+
| 3  | Becky    | NULL                |
+----+----------+---------------------+
| 1  | Jimmy    | Some Requirement    |
+----+----------+---------------------+
| 1  | Jimmy    | Another Requirement |
+----+----------+---------------------+
| 2  | John     | NULL                |
+----+----------+---------------------+
| 2  | John     | Some Requirement    |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, really big help. May I ask, what is your thought process when approaching problems like this? Do you start with the left join or cross join, and do you think of it as smaller queries first or start with the final data set you are aiming for? Thanks again.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ, i prefer smaller queries first and gradually building it for the final requirement.

Answer (score 1):

use left join, no need any subquery

```
select p.*,jr.*,jrr.* 
from People p left join
PeopleJobRequirements jr on p.Id=jrPersonId
left join JobRoleRequirements jrr p.id=jrr.PersonId
```

Answer (score 0):

according the explanation, People and PeopleJobRequirements tables have many to many relationship (n to n).
so first of all you'll need another table to relate these to table.
first do this and then a full join will make it right.